# record audio file as mp3 or wav

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, avaudiorecorder

I am trying to record and saave mp3 file so I use the following code

```
NSString* d = @" ar/mobile/Applications/86F15C5E-66EC-4071-95EB-96CDE64B5948/Library/Application Support/P/5720/5720/Report/Report0.mp3"

NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:d];

 NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary 
                                 dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],
                                 AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:16], 
                                 AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2], 
                                 AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0], 
                                 AVSampleRateKey,
                                 nil];

 NSError *error = nil;

 audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                  initWithURL:soundFileURL
                  settings:recordSettings
                  error:&error];

 if (error)
 {
     NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

 } else {
     [audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
 }
```

and to start record I use

```
[audioRecorder record];
```

for mp3 I got error 
error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1718449215.)

and if I saved it as wav nothing be recorded , and the file be 0 byte

am I missing something , any idea how to solve that

Answer (score 1):

you're not showing the way Dpath is defined...

```
NSString * filePath = [NSHomeDirectory()stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/%@.mp3",songTitle]];

// more code    

recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath settings: recordSettings error: nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps save it to the documents folder? Isn't that the correct legal path?